# need more info on dolphindb's snapshot engine

Tags: snapshot, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

I'm trying to monitor the latest data for each stock using dolphindb. But the data is not sorted in order. I'm wondering whether the snapshot engine can be used under this circumstance?

I just learned some basic examples from the tutorials. Could you please illustrate the prerequisites and limitations of the snapshot engine in detail?

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB provides the snapshot engine for the dfs tables. The engine saves snapshots of the latest data for each group upon data importing. When querying the latest records, DolphinDB only needs to retrieve the snapshots instead of the whole tables. Therefore, the engine's optimal performance is not affected by the number of records in a table. Note that the engine is only supported in standalone mode.

It is recommended to use the snapshot engine if the following conditions are met:

- you want to quickly query the latest records for each stock;
- the data is organized in chronological order;
- the system has sufficient memory left.

However, it is not appropriate to use the engine if the data cannot be sorted in chronological order. Otherwise, the acquired data may not be the latest.

The snapshot engine saves the snapshots for each group, so it will occupy more memory with a great number of data groups. It is not recommended to use the engine if memory is limited.